# Extracting representations from different layers of a network in TensorFlow 2

Tags: tensorflow2.0, feature-extraction, pre-trained-model, tensorflow-hub

I have the weights of a custom pre-trained model. I need to extract the representations for different inputs that I pass through the model, across its different layers. What would be the best way of doing this?

I am using TensorFlow 2.1.0 and currently load in the weights of the model using either hub.KerasLayer() or tf.saved_model.load()

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am very new to TensorFlow and have no choice but to use it since the weights were acquired from another source.

Answer (score 0):

tf.saved_model.load() and its wrapper hub.KerasLayer load both the computation graph and the pre-trained weights. I suppose you're dealing with a TF2-style SavedModel that has its computation packaged in TensorFlow functions. If so, there's no easy way to extract intermediate results from within a function. If possible, you could ask the model creator to provide more outputs, or, if you have the model's Python source, build the model from source and initialize its weights with those from the SavedModel (some plumbing required).